# Ambiguous result for 1<<31 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Why does `1<<31` print `18446744071562067968` as output when we run the following code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned long long int i = 1<<31;
    cout<<i; // this prints 18446744071562067968
}
```

Comment: `1` is an `int`, not an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Try `unsigned long long int i = 1UL << 31;`

Comment: You should include what you expect in the question, for the sake of completeness. These downvotes seem very unnecessary to me though. Even though I have a decent amount of C++ experience, it took me a minute to realize what was going on (especially having mostly programmed in a language for a while where the static type inference is done in a very different way and would give a different result).

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort. Googling either "site:stackoverflow.com "1 << 31"" or "site:stackoverflow.com "18446744071562067968"" would have easily given you the solution, even earlier if you include "c++".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1 is a `signed int`, which on your system is 32 bits.  `1 << 31` results in overflow, and is a negative number (`0x80000000`).  This, when converted to a 64 bit `unsigned long long` is then sign extended to 64 bits before being converted to the ULL value, which is `0xFFFFFFFF80000000`, or the large decimal number you see.

Comment: Hard to guess this was asked before I suppose. :/

Comment: But then, dupe votes yield not rep...